# React Native - IOS Push Notification - How to play ringtone when App is in Background?

Tags: swift, react-native, audio, background

On receiving notification I am showing custom screen and playing ringtone using InCallManager. On IOS if App is in background I get a notification pop-up. I can see the notification listener is also getting fired. I have placed the the same InCallManager function to play sound but nothing is getting played.

I have set the Background Modes -> Audio also in Xcode project.

Please can someone suggest how to play sound when the App is in Background?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by sending 'sound' field in the notification payload. I am using OneSignal so I am passing in the payload as:

'ios_sound' => 'ring.mp3'

And ring.mp3 is stored in my IOS Project.